# getting new conversation Id without refreshing the browser

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

i have microsoft bot framework webchat v3. i have one customization in UI of webchat. i have one custom button in the header section of bot. Clicking on the button refresh the browser and new conversation id will generated for the user.

I need one modification: clicking on the button available in header will create new conversation id without page refresh.
Is it possible? if yes, then how to handle this using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Web Chat v3 is no longer supported, and I would highly recommend [migrating to Web Chat v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#migrating-from-web-chat-v3-to-v4). There is an open PR to add a sample to the Web Chat repo showing how to restart a conversation. Take a look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1846#issuecomment-527216030) for more details.

If you are determined to accomplish this in v3, you can probably remove Web Chat from the DOM, request a new Direct Line token, recreate the bot connection, and then add Web Chat back to the screen.

Hope this helps!